# Markdown, Knitr, Pandoc Header block disappears from output when styles sheet is added

Tags: knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

```
---
title: "![logo](../Shared/logo.jpg)     Title Text"
author: "Author Name"
output: html_document
css: styles.css
---
```

This header information gets output with render or knit2html, but when the `css: styles.css` and associated code

```
options(rstudio.markdownToHTML = 
    function(inputFile, outputFile) {
    require(markdown)
    markdownToHTML(inputFile, outputFile, stylesheet='custom.css')
    } 
)
```

is added to the start up file, the rendered output file has no header output.  The first line in the file is the first line after the last "---" in the *.Rmd file.  By the way, "Knit HTML" on the individual *.Rmd content works as expected.

Thanks,
Alan

Answer (score 1):

The option `rstudio.markdownToHTML` is for [R Markdown v1](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_migrating_from_v1.html) only. The version based on Pandoc is v2, in which case the `css` field must be put under the `html_document` field:

```
---
title: "![logo](../Shared/logo.jpg)     Title Text"
author: "Author Name"
output:
  html_document:
    css: styles.css
---
```

Please [read the documentation](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html).